# Live Typescript Checking with Next.JS

Tags: typescript, next.js

The only way to check for TypeScript errors with Next.JS is to use `npm run build` (or `yarn build`).

If you run `npm run dev`, it won't show you TypeScript errors, which sucks because it would be nicer to see them in the Terminal window while you're developing.

Is there any way to make `npm run dev` show TS errors?

FYI - I REALLY don't like using my IDE to work with TS errors. Just my personal preference. I prefer to see them in the terminal window with all the other errors.

Comment: You may want to use a linter like tslint

Answer (score 13):

You can do something like this if you are using TS4+:

```
// package.json

{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "dev:ts": "yarn dev & yarn ts:watch", // <-- or use concurrently here
                                          // npmjs.com/package/concurrently
    "ts": "tsc --noEmit --incremental",
    "ts:watch": "yarn ts --watch"
  },

  // ...
}
```

You can also provide custom webpack config like this:

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
  webpack(config, { dev }) {
    if (dev) {
      const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin');
      config.plugins.push(new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin());
    }
    return config;
  },
};
```

The feature request is being tracked [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/14997).

Comment: This is only showing errors inside the terminal? want them shown inside screen what to do for that ?

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately, as of Next.js v9.4, [development typescript checks are disabled](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12735#issuecomment-626869676) since these checks significantly slow the development process. [Tim Neutkens states they expect this to happen on the IDE](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/12735#issuecomment-632054550).

And currently, there is no way to re-enable these checks.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue.
It turns out I started the project with a `.eslintrc` and did not specify **using with Typescript**. So, when I later added TypeScript into the project there were no TS errors.

What I did to fix the issue:

1. Removed `.eslistrc`
2. Launch `npx eslint --init` making sure I selected **using Typescript** and **To check syntax, find problems, and enforce code style**
3. Run `npm run dev` and it should be working